# Post content not showing

Tags: excerpt, content

I have this code that works perfect:

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5' . '&paged='.$paged);  
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<span><?php the_date('m/d/y'); ?></span>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button>Read More</button></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to display an excerpt of the post content between the date and button. So I added `<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>`. Didn't work. I tried `<p><?php get_the_content(); ?></p>`. Still nothing.

I tried putting the `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` loop around all of the HTML and just the paragraph. Both yielded nothing.

How do I get the excerpt to display?

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<span><?php the_date('m/d/y'); ?></span>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button>Read More</button></a>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Is your WordPress installation set up for debugging? If so, add `error_log( print_r( $my_query, true ) );` inside the loop. This will dump the value of `$my_query` into the log for each iteration through the `while` loop. On the surface your code looks correct to me.

Comment: @Cedon set up debugging and added the above statement into the loop. I got a bunch of stuff in the log that I don't know how to even begin to understand.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of one iteration in a code block?

Comment: The problem was resolved. Somehow the content of the post was deleted. So it was working correctly but there was no content to display.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is structured a little weird.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();

      // Your desired template code

   } // Close while()

   // Restore original Post Data
   wp_reset_postdata();

} // Close if()
```

This should be all you need to set it up since [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) pages by default unless you override it by setting `'nopaging' => true` in your arguments for it.

Note that after the `while()` loop ends, the statement `wp_reset_postdata();` is used. This resets the original post data to the defaults.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I made the suggested adjustments but `the_content()` still is not providing anything.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code you're trying including where you're calling `the_content()`?

Comment: Question has been updated